# What is the difference between OnClick and @onclick in blazor components

Tags: onclick, blazor

I found out something curious and I am wondering if anyone knows the answer:

First of all this is not this question:
[Different method calls in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777740/different-method-calls-in-blazor)
That question refers to HTML elements. I am talking about Components.

So I have my own component named MyButton; and it has OnClick Parameter specified:

MyButton.razor

```
<button @onclick="OnClick">Do Something</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

When I use MyButton I can use either the name exactly, i.e.

`<MyButton OnClick="SomeMethod" />`

But this is also working:

`<MyButton @onclick="SomeMethod" />`

When I remove the whole @code block from the MyButton.razor they both give me the exact same error message:

`<Mybutton OnClick="MyMethod" />`

> Object of type 'MyButton' does not have a property matching the name 'OnClick'.

`<Mybutton @onclick="MyMethod" />`

> Object of type 'MyButton' does not have a property matching the name 'onclick'.

The only difference is in the caps; "OnClick" vs "onclick"... that is logical. So it seems @onclick is the same as OnClick... but are they?

Is this simply an overload of some sorts?

Comment: I believe this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58778434/3291228)

Answer (score 3):

`@onclick` is the native HTML click event and `OnClick` is the event parameter you explicitly expose in your `MyButton` component.

So in this case you should use

`<MyButton OnClick="SomeMethod" />`

I tried to reproduce the usage with `@onclick` but it didn't work in my case.

For science, you could try to add a text `<p>Like this</p>` to your `MyButton` component and see if the `@onclick` event still works and if it only fires if you click the button or also if you click the text.

Also, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use MudBlazor ? Because I think `OnClick` is part of the MudBlazor Button API and `@onclick` is part of the ASP.NET Core Blazor event handling features.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31992454)

Comment: No I do not use that. It is in vanilla Blazor if I remember correctly.