# Why is a Lambda Function needed to pass a Value to a Method called by @onclick?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor (and web dev in general).  I was following along with [Microsoft's Blazor web app Todo List tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-a-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and after finishing said tutorial I wanted to go further and add buttons beside each list element to remove them from the list.  This is the code I wrote to accomplish that:

```
@page "/todo"

<h1>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
            <button @onclick="RemoveTodo(todo)">Remove</button>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Something to do" @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add todo</button>

@code {
    private List<TodoItem> todos = new();
    private string newTodo;
    
    private void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    
    private void RemoveTodo(TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            todos.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I could just copy the syntax from `<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add todo</button>` to add this button, but that introduces a bug.  As I found through [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962821/c-sharp-blazor-webassembly-argument-2-cannot-convert-from-void-to-microsoft), in order to fix this bug (and allow the app to build at all), I must change:

`<button @onclick="RemoveTodo(todo)">Remove</button>`

to include a lambda function like so:

`<button @onclick="() => RemoveTodo(todo)">Remove</button>`

I know that this change works, because I tested it and the app behaves as I intended it to!  But I want to *why* this change works.

I found this [additional Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777740/different-method-calls-in-blazor/58778434), wherein the chosen answer explains that in order to pass values to methods called by @onclick in the above manner, one must use a lambda expression.  The answer says that using `@onclick` will cause the compiler to create an EventCallback object to handle the code I provide to `@onclick`.

However, I still do not understand why my original code does not work.  I assume that the delegate being produced by the EventCallback object cannot execute properly when a value is being passed to the function it is executing.  The second question indicated that invoking via a lambda function produced a different kind of delegate, which *could* resolve the value passed to the function.

Is my understanding of what is happening close to the truth?  Why do I need to package functions inside lambda functions in this way, but only when said functions are being passed values?

Comment: The return type of `RemoveTodo` is `void`. When assigning to the `@onclick` property, you have to provide a value of the correct type, which is a delegate in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is about C# syntax. An eventhandler must be a delegate (a reference to a method).

The shortest way to show the error:

```
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add todo</button>         // ok
<button @onclick="AddTodo()">Add todo</button>       // error
<button @onclick="() => AddTodo()">Add todo</button> // ok
```

because, in plain C#:

```
delegate x = AddTodo;    // ok, a methodname w/o () means "address off"
delegate x = AddTodo();  // error, void is not a delegate
delegate x = () => AddTodo();  // ok, a lambda is a delegate
```

We usually prefer the first shorter version. But as soon as you have an argument you need the long form.

Comment: To be slightly annoying, you should be using discards `_` if you are not going to use the event args variable: `<button @onclick=" _ => AddTodo()">Add todo</button>` :)

Comment: Well... OnClick has (can have) an EventArgs but Blazor makes that optional. So I don't see any benefit in using a discard here. It is already solved in the .g.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over `@onclick` (or other `@events`) in any control, you will get information about the function that expects by default: a string or delegate value, and if it's a delegate, it should be of the type `MouseEventArgs` (in this case)

I wouldn't speculate as to why they did things one way or another, but the docs show examples for the various ways to handle events in Blazor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

IMO, the official docs are usually very good.  I usually google "MSDN BLAZOR ____" to find what I want.